# Laravel Authentication on Backpaging through History

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, browser-history

I have a middleware group defined as:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('home', 'Home@Redirect');
    Route::get('create','Create@Redirect');
    Route::get('settings', 'Settings@Redirect');
);
```

When someone logs out i redirect them to the login page i then call the Auth::Logout() which works fine because they can then no longer navigate through the site.

The Issue is that when you backspace though the browsers history then can navigate backwards through the site, but they will be kicked out if they click a link to try to navigate through the site.

An example would be, Im on the home page and then i log out. I click the backspace and get back to the Home page. I i then try to click a link on the home page that requires me to be authenticated i get kicked out... but i should not have be able to backpage into my history to get back to the homepage.

If this is not clear i can further elaborate or prove more code. I am on Laravel 5.0

Comment: You can fix this by setting a cache control header, typically from some middleware, you would call: `$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate', true);`

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an issue with Laravel it's just web browser behavior.

Like you mentioned clicking on a link to a protected page after logout, throws you out with access denied which means Laravel middleware works perfectly.

I believe you can control this browser behavior on client side by using JavaScript.

Or

You can change headers of all your restricted area informing the browser the content must not be cached.

Or

You could add this to the HTML head tag of all the pages you don't wish to cache.

```
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="private, max-age=0, no-cache"> 

 <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">

 <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

Comment: This is great information thank you. The issue is that it is being cached you are correct. I have tried the meta tags but the issue seems to persist. The reason i know its the cache is that when i log out and then clear the cache i am unable to backpage because the redirect triggers. I will have to play around with this but thank you for pointing me into the right path about the cached view :-)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases (if not all), pressing the back button does not trigger a new request, so therefor the only way to implement a "lockout" would be on the client side via Javascript (or flavor thereof).

Chances are you're using blade and a master layout, so simply include some Javascript that detects a window change on each page throughout your site. On (re)entry, fire off a Ajax call to your server that returns true/false based on their login state. If they're not logged in, use JS to redirect to the login page.

One thing to note: anyone with any knowledge of JS could easily bypass this "check," but it would serve its purpose for most users to your site. Luckily, all this means is that a user would be able to see the page exactly as they saw it before they logged in. No security implications at that point.

Comment: Thank you this seems like a good work around for now i will try it and let you know if it works well, but it does seem like a short term quick fix as it is a client side implementation. THANKS :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You must create a middleware that intercepts the page call, clearing the cache

```
$ php artisan make:middleware RevalidateBackHistory
```

overwrite the function HANDLE

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache')
            ->header('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
```

I'll add it to the kernel.php in array   $routeMiddleware

```
'revalidate' => \App\Http\Middleware\RevalidateBackHistory::class,
```

and group them

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'revalidate'], function()
{
    // Routes that you want to revalidate go in here
});
```